# Surface plot of equally spaced grid of overlapping Gaussians not plotting correctly?

Tags: octave, surface

I am attempting to make a surface plot in Octave based on a bunch of overlapping, offset curves. the function should be treating x and y identically but I am not seeing that in the final plot, rather it has ridges running along one axis. I cant tell if this is a plotting error or something else wrong with my code. am hoping you can provide some help/insight.

[Plot with ridges following one axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2zaN.png)

Thanks

```
clear;
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
V = 2500; %scan speed in mm
rr = 200000; %rep rate in Hz
Qsp = 1; %pulse energy
pi = 3.14159;
ns = 1; %scan number
w = 0.0125; %Gaussian radius in mm
dp = 0.0125; %lateral pulse distance in mm
dh = 0.0125; %hatch pitch in mm
xmax = 0.2; %ablation area x in mm
ymax = 0.2; %ablation area y in mm
np = round(xmax/dp); 
nh = round(ymax/dh);
points = 50;
cof = ns*2*Qsp/(pi*w^2);
N = [0:1:np];
M = rot90([0:1:nh]);
for i = 1:points
   for j = 1:points
    x = (i-1)*xmax/(points-1);
    y = (j-1)*ymax/(points-1);
    k = exp(-(2*(x-N*dp).^2+(y-M*dh).^2)/(w^2));
    H(i,j) = cof*sum(sum(k));
  endfor
endfor
ii = [1:1:points];
jj = ii;
xx = (ii-1)*xmax/(points-1);
yy = (jj-1)*ymax/(points-1);
surf(xx,yy,H);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to space out components of complex expressions.

```
k = exp(-(2*(x-N*dp).^2+(y-M*dh).^2)/(w^2));
```

It's too hard to read with so many parentheses.

```
k = exp(
         -(
            2*(x-N*dp).^2  +  (y-M*dh).^2
          ) / (w^2)
       );
```

Do you see it already?

```
k = exp(
         -(
                2 * (x-N*dp).^2  
          +
                    (y-M*dh).^2
          ) / (w^2)
       );
```

The x component gets multiplied by two, but the y component doesn't.

Comment: @Helios : if this was useful, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).